# File format not recognized; treating as linker script using GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, makefile, compilation

I am pretty new to Makefiles and i am trying to build an executable from 3 files,  file1.c, file2.c, and file1.h into an executable called exFile. Here's what I got:

```
all: exFile
exFile: file1.o file2.o 
    gcc -Wall -g -m32 repeat.o show.o -o repeat

file1.o: file1.c file1.h
    gcc -Wall -g -m32 -S file1.c -o file1.o

file2.o: file2.c 
    gcc -Wall -g -m32 -S file2.c -o file2.o
```

I've searched the web for makefiles in this format, but i came up empty handed so i was wondering if someone can help.  When it tries to compile i get:

```
usr/bin/ld:file1.o:1: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
```

I've compiled programs using assembly files but I'm not to sure what to do with c files or the file1.h file.  file1.c includes file1.h so i have to link them (I think?).  Any suggestions or links to a reference would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two problems with your `gcc` command-line.  First, you're specifying the `-S` flag, which causes gcc to emit assembly code, rather than object code.  Second, you're missing the `-c` flag, which tells gcc to compile the file to an object file, but not link it.  If you just remove `-S` and change nothing else, you'll end up with an executable program named `file1.o` and another named `file2.o`, rather than two object files.

Besides those errors, you could simplify your makefile by the use of pattern rules.  I suggest you try the following instead:

```
all: exFile
exFile: file1.o file2.o 
    gcc -Wall -g -m32 $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc -Wall -g -m32 -c $< -o $@

file1.o: file1.h
```

Or, as EmployedRussian points out, you can go with something even more minimal that leverages more of the built-in features of GNU make:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -m32

all: exFile

exFile: file1.o file2.o 
        $(LINK.c) $^ -o $@

file1.o: file1.h
```

Comment: This makefile is still quite bad. You don't need a pattern rule -- make has one just like it already built in. Also, exFile will always be out of date, because you are building "repeat" instead. If you are providing an example of how to correct the makefile, please do a better job of it!

Comment: @Employed Russian:  oops, thanks for catching that typo (copied from the OP).  As for simplifying the makefile, yes, it could be simpler, but I'm not sure doing so would help the OP's understanding, given that it's not the makefile structure that was causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `-S` switch to gcc tells it to output assembler so this:

```
gcc -Wall -g -m32 -S file1.c -o file1.o
```

Is putting assembler into `file1.o` but you want, presumably, to compile `file1.c` into object code:

```
gcc -Wall -g -m32 file1.c -o file1.o
```

When the linker gets your `file1.o` it is confused because `file1.o` is assembler when the linker is expecting object code, hence your error.

So get rid of the `-S` switches for `file1.o` and `file2.o`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still no luck...getting the same error.  Im totally stumped on this.  I'll research it more I know I'm not that far off probably just some detail I overlooked.

Comment: @user695978: What happens if you `file file1.o` to get the file type?